# Regarding hls stream can't work on iphone

Tags: http-live-streaming

I use ffmpeg to deliver my av streams(video:h264 ,baseline3.1; audio:aac,8000,stereo) to nginx,then I used iphone's chrome or safari to access this stream, and failed. But I tested it on android's chrome or pc's chome safari, they all worked.
Is there any specifical requirement on iphone?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason you appear to be having this issue could be your server is not set up to support **byte-range requests**, which is necessary for media files to be able to be played back on iOS devices.

For more information, please see the [Configuring Your Server section in Apple’s documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6).

You may try something like below on your site's Nginx config.

```
# byte-range requests 
    location ~ \.(mp4|m4a|m4v|mov)$ {
        add_header content_disposition filename=$request_uri;
        add_header accept_ranges bytes;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I found that it's not the reason why I can' access the hsl stream through my iphone. I guess the iphone needs to download all the ts files which are included in m3u8 file.